# My App Crash on Oreo .saying app has stopped open app again

Tags: javascript, android

This is the log cat. pls fix this issue for me .i have updated api version to 28 already.can any one help me pls.i want to fix this issue fast.try do resolve fast.im so confused.i need help guys pls help me.im using android studio new version also.

```html
07-14 23:56:05.106 9597-9597/com.sinhalagossip.Blogger.Tharu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sinhalagossip.Blogger.Tharu, PID: 9597
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(142222500bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
        at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1349)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19192)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1966)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:788)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
07-14 23:56:33.659 9597-9635/com.sinhalagossip.Blogger.Tharu E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

Comment: You need to include code causing the exception. Also exception is pretty clear, you're trying to draw a 142 MEGABYTE image.

Comment: how can i do that. i'm still learning coding.pls help me how can i do that. thanks.

Comment: how can i do that.pls guide me steps

Answer (score 1):

I think the image you are trying to use is too large, so the device is running out of memory whilst trying to resize it. Try resizing the image outside of android studio, then run it again.

Hope this helps,

Owen

Comment: Yep, according to the logs you're trying to render a 142MB(!) picture.

Comment: can you guide me step by step.please.

Comment: Just crop or resize the image in an editor such as Photoshop. You can even use MS Paint if you really wanted to! Any photo editor should be able to crop or resize an image.

Comment: i mean which image should i resize and where i can found that image on project.

Comment: In the resources folder you should have all the images that you use in your project. Have a look through and there should be at least one large image that is causing your app to crash. I can't tell what image is causing the crash just from the log.

Comment: ok i will try to find

Comment: still same issure :( can any one fix my issue.i can send the project file